# Is it possible to access visual component using tag?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I hope to access visual component (such a button) using tag.
It is easy on android, but I am not sure if it is possible on wp7.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? it doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controls are in a collection that implements `IEnumerable<FrameworkElement>` you can use LINQ:

```
var controlQuery = from ctrl in collection
                   where ctrl.Tag.Equals(thingInTag)
                   select ctrl
```

If not you would first have to [collect all the child controls](http://johnleitch.blogspot.com/2010/04/wpf-find-all-child-controls-of-type.html) (it's WPF but should work in WP7 too)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just access it by its x:Name. That's the equivalent to Android except that you don't have to do extra steps. In the code behind file all you have to do is type the name and press period and you'll get all its public properties, events, etc.